# Change imageButton State when Scolling HorizontalView in android using TwoWayView

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, onscroll

**NOTE: Anyone, no idea how to do this??**

TwoWayView libary to display images on horizontally on imagebutton, all images displayed 
succesfully.

**My problem:**

when i scoll horizontalview using TwoWayView, then only change imagebutton background

```
(like when load 
ui then imagebutton background will be display colored and onscolling time then all
imagebutton background will be grayscale and after stop scolling then again imagebutton
background will be initail phase ie colored)
```

for certain second.

Here, anohter problem is how to use GPUImage for grayscale change and revert to colored.
I convert successfully on IOS but unable to use this android.

I am trying to use programmtically set imagebutton state because i don;t know images
because it comes from server sothat.

```
    StateListDrawable stateList = new StateListDrawable();
    stateList.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused}, dataImage.get(1));
    stateList.addState(new int[] {},  dataImage.get(0));
    holder.imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(stateList);
```

Using **Custom Adapter, Here is the FUllCode:** http://pastebin.com/c1v0WAYA

Now , Back to MainActivity, What i have done:

**Full Code -  MainActivity:** http://pastebin.com/MHERB89j
I have declared TwoWayView, and implemention

```
String stateName;
      mListView = new TwoWayView(getApplicationContext());
        mListView.setItemMargin(10);
        mListView.setLongClickable(true);
        mListView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);


        mListView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mListView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

         mListView.setOnScrollListener(new TwoWayView.OnScrollListener() {
            private boolean scrolling=false;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(TwoWayView view, int scrollState) {
                stateName = "Undefined";
                switch(scrollState) {
                case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                    stateName = "Idle";
                    break;

                case SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
                    stateName = "Dragging";
                    break;

                case SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
                    stateName = "Flinging";
                    break;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(final TwoWayView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                int childcount = view.getChildCount();
                Log.e("STATE", "state Name="+stateName);
                if (stateName.equalsIgnoreCase("Flinging")) {
                     for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
                         view.getChildAt(i).setSelected(true);
                     }
                }else if (stateName.equalsIgnoreCase("Idle")) {
                 for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
                     view.getChildAt(i).setSelected(false);
                    }
                }else {
                    for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
                     view.getChildAt(i).setSelected(false);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

My intention is change image colored *but* here my example just change image **dataImage.get(0)** in intitial and edle state
and **dataImage.get(1)** image background when flinging state.

Output: when scolling right side image disappers and when right to left then nothing any effect.